# Bringing arguments into java input output method

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to bring 2 arrays and one integer from a different method into the method that writes the file. I tried bringing in using arguments but it is not working. Hope you can help

This is how i passed argument from method holding the arry informations.

```
write (NameX, ScoresArray, players); /
```

This is the method that is meant to use the passed array arguments to create file.

```
public static void write (String NameX [], int ScoresArray [], int players ) throws IOException 
{
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Genius.txt"));


    outputStream.println(players);

    for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
    {
            outputStream.println(NameX[i] + ScoresArray [i] );
    }

    outputStream.close();



}
```

This is the method that reads the file

```
public static void reads () throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Genius.txt"));

    // Read in first file entry as an integer - the number of names stored       
    int players = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());
    System.out.println(players);

    // Create an array big enough
    String [] NameX = new String[players];
    String [] ScoresArray = new String[players];

    // Now read in the names
    for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
    {
        NameX[i] = inStream.readLine();
        ScoresArray[i] = inStream.readLine();

        System.out.println(NameX[i]);
        System.out.println(ScoresArray[i]);
    }

    inStream.close();



}
```

Please could you tell me where i am going wrong and how i can create a file that saves the arrays and reads the file later.

************* Edited code********************

```
    write(NameX,ScoresArray,players);
   reads();
    }


}//end of league table


public static void write (String NameX [], int ScoresArray [], int players ) throws IOException
```

{

```
PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Genius.txt"));


outputStream.println(players);

for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
{
        outputStream.println(NameX[i] +":"+ ScoresArray [i] );
}

outputStream.close();
```

}
  public static void reads () throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Genius.txt"));

```
// Read in first file entry as an integer - the number of names stored       
int players = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());
System.out.println(players);

// Create an array big enough
String [] NameX = new String[players];
String [] ScoresArray = new String[players];

// Now read in the names
for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
{
    String str = inStream.readLine();
    String vals[] = str.split(":");
    System.out.println(vals[0]+"   "+vals[1]);
}

inStream.close();
```

}

i am still getting same issue

Comment: What problem you are facing, are you getting any Exception.. etc.

Comment: it says unreported IOException: must be caught or displayed to be thrown. the error is for the line where i call the write method and pass the arrays.

Comment: Actually, you are doing file handling where check exception my occur. Java doc says that you have to provide exception handling for checked exception. so put try-catch block where you are initializing the class and performing read/write operation on the file and then check the output and let me know the further issue.

Answer (score 0):

[IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is a checked Exception and your function `write (NameX, ScoresArray, players);` is throws  `IOException`.
So you should handle it in caller.

```
try {
   write (NameX, ScoresArray, players); //
}catch(IOException ie){
  // do operation 
}
```

For more details See: [Lesson: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Comment: is this how its meant to look?

Comment: is this how it is meant to look?public static void write ()
 
 try {
    write (NameX, ScoresArray, players); //
 }
 
 catch(IOException ie)
 {
   PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Genius.txt"));
 
 
        outputStream.println(players);
                    
        for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
        {
                outputStream.println(NameX[i] + ScoresArray [i] );
        }
        
        outputStream.close();
 }

Comment: @jeeps95 No, // do operation means handle the Exception. don't put your code  inside catch.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i hope you are looking for this :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 *
 * @author manoj.sharma
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void write (String NameX [], int ScoresArray [], int players ) throws IOException 
{
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Genius.txt"));


    outputStream.println(players);

    for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
    {
            outputStream.println(NameX[i] +":"+ ScoresArray [i] );
    }

    outputStream.close();



}
  public static void reads () throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Genius.txt"));

    // Read in first file entry as an integer - the number of names stored       
    int players = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());
    System.out.println(players);

    // Create an array big enough
    String [] NameX = new String[players];
    String [] ScoresArray = new String[players];

    // Now read in the names
    for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++)
    {
        String str = inStream.readLine();
        String vals[] = str.split(":");
        System.out.println(vals[0]+"   "+vals[1]);
    }

    inStream.close();



}  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] names={"manoj","kushal"};
        int [] scores = {10,20};
        int p = 2;
       try{
       write(names,scores,p);
       reads();
      } catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

    }

}
```

I hope you have found your solution.

Comment: please kindly check the edited code i have added above, it is still giving errors

Comment: Actually, you are getting exception just check my code. I have put colon[:] symbol while writing and i have split string while reading using colon[:] symbol. You are not doing so you first loop cycle read will return output and second cycle will give exception. So you have to modify you code yourself like i have modified to fit your requirement.

Comment: Put your all code. My code is working perfectly on my system and i am getting this output:  2
manoj   10
kushal   20. Without any exception error message.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using java.lang.Exception rather than IOException, using Exception should cover all types of exceptions that could be thrown.

```
public static void write (String NameX [], int ScoresArray [], int players ) throws Exception
{
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Genius.txt"));
    outputStream.println(players);

    for (int i = 0; i < NameX.length; i++){
        outputStream.println(NameX[i] + ScoresArray [i] );
    }

    outputStream.close();
}
```

And then use:

```
try {
   write (NameX, ScoresArray, players); //
}catch(IOException io){
    //Handle an IO exception
}catch(Exception e){
    //Handle Exception
}
```

I'm afraid I havent had time to test this though.